# forks and pipes, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, system-calls

I'm trying to learn about pipes and redirections. For this purpose I'm doing some little programs to get used to the related system calls. On this one, I'm trying to launch cat on a file, pipe4.c, and pipe its output to grep that I launch after. It doesn't work and I don't understand the results,
I though that the logic was good but I'm clearly missing something with fork. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #define BUFF_SIZE 4092

    //redirecting the output of a program ('cat' here)
    //to the stdin of another program ('grep' here)
    void    err_handler(char *msg)
    {
        perror(msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        //creating a pipe to communicate between the child processes
        int p[2];
        if (pipe(p) < 0)
            err_handler("pipe error: ");
        /*
        ** forking for cat
        */
        pid_t cat_pid;
        if ((cat_pid = fork()) < 0)
            err_handler("fork error: ");
        if (cat_pid)
            close(p[1]);
        if (!cat_pid) {
            printf("===CAT===\n");
            dup2(p[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(p[0]);
            close(p[1]);
            execl("/bin/cat", "cat", "pipe4.c", NULL);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        /*
        ** forking for grep
        */
        pid_t grep_pid;
        if ((grep_pid = fork()) < 0)
            err_handler("fork_error: ");
        if (grep_pid)
            wait(&grep_pid);
        if (!grep_pid) {
            printf("===GREP===\n");
            dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(p[0]);
            close(p[1]);
            execl("/bin/grep", "grep", "\"err_handler\"", NULL);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        return 0;

}
```

I only get this on my terminal:

```
> pom@parrot ~/dev/19/syscall> sudo ./a.out 
> ===GREP===
> ===CAT===
> ===GREP===
```

The order in which those lines are printed changes each time I execute it.
What I expect is obviously all the lines containing "err_handler" in my pipe4.c file, like if I did it directly in the shell:

```
> pom@parrot ~/dev/19/syscall> cat pipe4.c | grep "err_handler"
> void  err_handler(char *msg)      err_handler("pipe error: ");
>       err_handler("fork error: ");            err_handler("creat error: ");
>               err_handler("read error: ");
>               err_handler("write error:");
```

Comment: Why is the parent waiting for `cat`?  If the data stream is large, cat is going to block on a write, and `grep` will never be executed.  You should exec both grep and cat before watiing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I removed it. This doens't resolve my problem though. I only get the 'printf', so maybe the problem's in the pipes?

Comment: You're not using the `wait` function correctly.

Comment: As I said I removed the wait, something else I'm missing?

Comment: It would help if you explained what "doesn't work" means precisely, and what results you are seeing.  Is the process terminating with unexpected results, is it hanging, is it segfaulting?  "doesn't work" is not a particularly good description of the issue.

Comment: I edited my question @WilliamPursell. The program doesn't crash or terminate with any error, nor is it hanging. It just doesn't do anything beside printing those printfs, when it should print the output of "grep" as well.

Comment: You are still not using wait correctly.   In the second instance, `wait` is writing a value into grep_pid.  Also, you should really flush your output streams before you dup the file descrptors.

Comment: So I just use wait(NULL); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (I think!) 3 major issues.

1) you are not using wait correctly.  I would advise using waitpid instead.

2) at least on my system, /bin/grep does not exist.  It is /usr/bin/grep.  But since you are returning EXIT_SUCCESS when `exec` fails, you aren't seeing an error.  You should replace `execl (...); exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`, with `execl(...); perror("execl"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

3) You are searching for literal quotes. It is as if you ran:

```
grep '"err_handler"'
```

That is, the argument to execl when you spawn grep should be `"err_handler"`, not `"\"err_handler\""`

Comment: Thanks, the third point was the problem. I though by escaping quotes it would be equivalent to writing [grep "err_handler"] in the terminal. And yes I was using wait() but meant to "do" a waitpid(), thanks for pointing that out. grep is in /bin/ in my system though!